# How can I start an Android AlphaAnimation, at a certain time?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have this ImageButton. I want it to start animating at a certain time.
I looked into android documentation, and found [setStartTime(long startTimeMillis)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setStartTime%28long%29).

This is what I came up with:

```
private ImageButton imgBtn;

// Other variables and stuff..

//And inside to onCreate void, I have set the button listener.
imgBtn.setOnClickListener(tappClickHandler);
    Button.OnClickListener imgClickHandler = new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new AsyncTaskExample().execute("");

        }
    };
    private class AsyncTaskExample extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            AlphaAnimation alDown = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.1f);
            alDown.setDuration(200);
            alDown.setFillAfter(true);
            imgBtn.startAnimation(alDown);
        }
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
            Date test = new Date();
            return (test.getTime()/1000) + 5;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            Date clientTime = new Date();

            AlphaAnimation alUp = new AlphaAnimation(0.1f, 1.0f);
            alUp.setDuration(200);
            alUp.setStartTime(result);
            imgBtn.setAnimation(alUp);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Time to start: " + imgBtn.getAnimation().getStartTime());
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Current device time: " + clientTime.getTime()/1000);    
        }

    }
```

The log prints:

02-13 20:40:42.634: D/tappWin(3504): Time to start: 1329162048

02-13 20:40:42.634: D/tappWin(3504): Current device time: 1329162042

The imgBtn makes the first animation, but not the second..

Comment: When I use [startAnimation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#startAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)) it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely way too much work being done to try and track the animation times.  The exact reason your current code isn't working well is because `setStartTime()` must be called in the context of the time values returned by `AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis()` instead of the system time.

However, a much simpler approach is to use an `AnimationListener` object to notify you when the first animation is complete in order to start the second one.  In other words:

```
Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.1f);
fadeOut.setDuration(500);
fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0.1f, 1.0f);
        fadeIn.setDuration(500);
        imgBtn.startAnimation(fadeIn);
    }
});

imgBtn.startAnimation(fadeOut);
```

HTH

Comment: Hi, thanks for the respond!


The reason that I have the AsyncTask, is because the client don't know when the animation should fadeIn again. Only the server does.

What I didn't post, was the comm. with the server - sorry :P

The return [code]((test.getTime()/1000) + 5;) was just to demonstrate an example of the server response.

- Kristian

Comment: Understood.  If you want to set the start time from a server like that, you need to do a conversion between system time and animation time; i.e. your task should return the offset value in terms of the `currentAnimationTimeMillis()` I mentioned so it is set properly on the `Animation`.

Comment: Could I use the [setStartOffset(long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setStartOffset(long)) instead?

Comment: Yes.  That will create an offset in millis from the start time, which by default is immediately after you call set/start.